# How to prevent the wildcard namespace in struts?

Tags: struts2, struts2-namespace

I am facing a problem that I couldn't find a key word for googleing the following situation:

```
<package name="Main" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="administrator" class="com.xyz.AdminAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/admin.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

The above url should be **http://xyz.com/administrator** and it works fine. However, if I change the url to **http://xyz.com/asdasd/asdasdasd/administrator** and it still works, but I can't accept this! So any setting to tell struts only **http://xyz.com/administrator** is accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Beware. If you've configured your Struts application in this particular way (setting 'alwaysSelectFullNamespace' to 'true'), your application is very likely vulnerable to CVE-2018-11776: https://semmle.com/news/apache-struts-CVE-2018-11776

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `alwaysSelectFullNamespace` property to `true`.

From `struts-default.properties`:

```
### Whether to always select the namespace to be everything before the last slash or not
struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace=true
```

XML configuration is preferred, so in your `struts.xml`:

```xml
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="true" />
  ...
```