# Wrong URL match in action mapping

Tags: java, struts2, pattern-matching, wildcard-mapping

```xml
<action name="/partner/*/*" class="webStoreAction">
    <param name="saveUrl">true</param>
    <param name="homeName">HomePartner</param>
    <param name="partner">{1}</param>
    <param name="partnerId">{2}</param>
    <param name="homeFromMenu">false</param>
    <result name="success" type="jsf">
        /WEB-INF/pages/load.xhtml
    </result>
</action>
```

Why `localhost:8080/partner/partnerName` matches with this action?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26235071/1700321.

Comment: What a pattern matcher is configured?

Comment: in my struts.xml `<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
 <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false" />`. sorry @RomanC "/partner/*/*" this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/>` the only viable matcher for the constants above. This is usually used with advanced wildcards mode, explained [here](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings#advanced-wildcards).

> Advanced Wildcards
> From 2.1.9+ regular expressions can be defined defined in the action name. To use this form of wild card, the following constants must be set:

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
```

The URL splitted into namespace `/` and action name `partner/partnerName`. The last matches a pattern compiled from the name in the action config using a wildcard mapper, which is a default mapper.