# Struts2 Wildcard Mapping - more specific one is being handled by generic one

Tags: java, struts2, pattern-matching, mapping, wildcard

I'm currently playing around with my Struts2 config for wildcard testing and I'm stuck with this one.

```xml
    <action name="/*/*" class="checkBlogUrl" method="testing">
        <param name="blogSiteUrl">{1}</param>
        <param name="test">{2}</param>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/cmsPages/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="/*/postPreview1" class="blogPostAction" method="test">
        <param name="blogSiteUrl">{1}</param>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/cmsPages/templatePicker.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

If I access `myurl.com/hello/hi` I will be redirected to `index.jsp`.

But if I access `myurl.com/hello/postPreview1` I will also be redirected to `index.jsp` instead of `templatePicker.jsp`.

Am I doing something wrong here? The [struts wildcard doc](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings.html) said that the last one will win

**EDIT:**

Just tried to switch them around and it worked! Am I misreading the doc?

Comment: What is `/hello`? Is it a context path?

Comment: See https://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-WildcardDefault.

Comment: @RomanC I'm not sure about the meaning of context path. the /hello can be any word, i need to query it if exists in the database. the next slash are actions

Comment: @AleksandrM hm but the default wont work for me since I need to have specific actions on the last slash (eg: postPreview1, hi). I'm just baffled that my wildcards are working on a different way that were declared in the doc

Comment: Why it is different? Your `/*/*` looks similar to `*`.

Comment: does it work that way? I wanted to "force" it so that the /*/* will trigger if and only if there are two slashes because i need the two variables ({1}, {2})

Comment: @JiroManio No, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Read the docs. -> *It's important to put a "catchall" wildcard mapping like this at the end of your configuration so it won't attempt to map every request!*

Comment: Hm thanks. I've added it. Will play around it again

Comment: The ball to your gate http://stackoverflow.com/q/26741967/573032

Comment: @RomanC oh so that's how. Thanks. Can you post an answer, or tag this question as duplicate?

Comment: @JiroManio Done. See the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using slashes in action name, that incorrectly works with wildcard mapper. As I said in the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747410/573032), the best pattern matcher in this case is the `regex` pattern matcher.

```xml
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/>
```

See [Advanced Wildcards](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings#advanced-wildcards).

```xml
<action name="/{blogSiteUrl}/{test}" class="checkBlogUrl" method="testing">
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/cmsPages/index.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="/{blogSiteUrl}/postPreview1" class="blogPostAction" method="test">
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/cmsPages/templatePicker.jsp</result>
</action>
```

---

About docs for wildcard mapper. Lets look at the example *blank* application:

```xml
<package name="example" namespace="/example" extends="default">

    <action name="HelloWorld" class="example.HelloWorld">
        <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/example/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="Login_*" method="{1}" class="example.Login">
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/example/Login.jsp</result>
        <result type="redirectAction">Menu</result>
    </action>

    <action name="*" class="example.ExampleSupport">
        <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/example/{1}.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <!-- Add actions here -->
</package>
```

---

So URLs will be matched in the order:

1. `http://localhost:8080/example/HelloWorld`
2. `http://localhost:8080/example/Login_input`
3. `http://localhost:8080/example/Register`

I would say that more specific mapping goes before less specific/common mapping and it wins because it's found first in the order of action configs. Everything that doesn't match the ordered configs fall into last mapping which is less specific.

Comment: Hello, can you add an example how annotation approach will looks like in this case?

Comment: `<package name="action" namespace="/" extends="rest-default,json-default">
<action name="/{uid}/hello/{id}" class="com.wildcard.action.HelloController">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonStack"/>
            <result type="json"/>
        </action></package>` I have this in my struts.xml, along with the xml tag for patternMatcher with the value of regex. But I get the error `There is no Action mapped for action name 2` when I access using the URL `http://localhost:8080/wildcard_sample/2/hello/3.json`. I am using `Struts 2.5.29`. @Roman C

Answer (score 0):

In your case,from the official docs,

`Mappings are matched against the request in the order they appear in the framework’s configuration file. If more than one pattern matches the last one wins, so less specific patterns must appear before more specific ones. However, if the request URL can be matched against a path without any wildcards in it, no wildcard matching is performed and order is not important.`

https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings.html#wildcards