# How Struts wild card mapping precedence work?

Tags: java, struts

I have a struts mapping `/somename/**` which will be called whenever my URL path starts at `/somename/`.
Then I have `/somename/othername/**` struts mapping which is not being called since `/somename/**` being prioritized.The code was placed before `/somename/**`

The quick fix is to use `/othername/othername/**`, however it will be difficult to request for a change in the URL format.
I tried `/somename/othername/*` for some reason I only see it works once but never again.

Is there a way to call `/somename/othername/**` and not `/somename/**`?

Comment: The other option I have is to add the complete path in the struts, however this will required code change every time we need to add the same URL format. This is a maintenance overhead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36887123/573032